# What are the functions and differences between axons and dendrites?

Tags: neuroscience, terminology, neurophysiology

My textbook doesn't do a very good job of pointing out what the differences between the two are. It basically mentions axons only in the same breath as the synapse (that synapses are the endings/tips of axons).

Comment: how about some other textbook, wiki, google? how is this question OK for Bio@SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This reference](http://www.gwinnett.k12.ga.us/LilburnES/PromoteGA/biochemistry/Neuron_a_and_d.html) is a bit basic, but lists the functions and differences between axons and dendrites.  Specifically, dendrites receive signals from other neurons, to the cell body; whereas, axons take signals away from the cell body (essentially 'input-output').  A diagram of the parts and the processes is below:

[image: Neuron]

([Image source with additional information)](http://www.appsychology.com/Book/Biological/neuroscience.htm)

[This Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86EBfEz6CYA) is a nice visual description of both, and how they function within a neuron.

Comment: Can you provide some details in your answer rather than just links?

Comment: @kmm is this acceptable?

Comment: no synapse.. hmm

Comment: @Lesbihonest The synapses are just not labelled on the diagram, but are referred to in the links.

Answer (score 1):

**[Dendrites](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/psychology/courses/1010/mangels/neuro/neurocells/neurocells.html)**

- Means ***Trees*** in Greek;
- Are the **input** of the neuron;
- **Receive information** from other neurons or the external environment;
- **Transfer information** to the cell body and axons;
- Are **numerous**, relatively **short**, and **branch** extensively in a tree-like fashion
- May have numerous **spines** on them to provide a greater surface area for other neurons to synapse on;
- **Receive information** from other cells at these synapses. This makes dendrites **postsynaptic**.
- The connection between axons that synapse on dendrites is called **axodendritic**;
- The connection between dendrites that synapse on other dendrites is called **dendrodendritic**.

**[Axon](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/psychology/courses/1010/mangels/neuro/neurocells/neurocells.html)** 
 - Means ***axis*** in Greek

- The **output** of the neuron;
- **Transfers information** to other neurons;
- Begins at the **axon hillock**, which is a swelling at the junction of the axon and soma where there are many Na<sup>+</sup> channels and the action potential starts;
- Is relatively **long** (some reaching several feet);
- Has terminal **boutons** at the end where the synapse is located. This makes axons **presynaptic**. These swellings at the terminal bouton is where the neuron synapses with another neuron;
- Contains numerous **vesicles** which hold **neurotransmitter**;
- Has many **Ca<sup>2+</sup> channels** in the membrane;
- The space between the terminal boutons and the next cell is known as the **synaptic cleft**, and is approximately 20 nm thick;
- Most are **myelinated**, i.e., have myelin sheaths that are made by Schwann cells or oligodendrocytes. Myelin acts as insulator to help conduction of action potential. There are openings between the Schwann cells called **Nodes of Ranvier**. These help with the conduction of action potentials.
- **Synapse** on other cells in various forms;
- **Axoaxonal**: Axon is connected to another neuron’s axon;
- **Axodendritic**: Axon is connected to another neuron’s dendrites
- **Axosomatic**: Axon is connected directly to another neuron’s soma
- In **neuromuscular junctions**, axons synapse directly on muscles.

[image: synapse]
<sup>Presynaptic and postsynaptic neuron. The synapse is shown enlarged in the inset. Source: [Rowland Hall](http://www.rhsmpsychology.com/Handouts/synapse.htm).</sup>