# Can axons act as receptors?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, histology

In all histology books, it is stated that all sensory nerve endings (receptors) consist of dendrites that translate physical stimuli from the environment into neural signals. However, several sensory neurons seem to include axons, such as the merkel and olfactory cells shown below. They act as receptors, but feature axons as well. So is it the pictures, or the texts that are incorrect?

[image: merkel cell innervation]

[image: olfactory cells]

Comment: Axon is a kind of dendrite actually..

Comment: What exactly is your question? Whether 1) axons are part of sensory neurons, or whether 2) axons can have sensory function (given that dendrites typically act as receptor)? Please clarify.

Comment: @AliceD Sort of, technically they both are cytoplasmic processes.

Comment: @AliceD I just said axon is a kind of dendrite — a specialized one (both of them are grouped together as *neurites*, btw). So there is no argument here. Moreover, unlike apples and pears, dendrites and axons are the part of the same biological entity.

Comment: I removed the apples and the pears - bad analogy :) But I can't settle for an axon and dendrite being similar - http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9026/what-are-the-functions-and-differences-between-axons-and-dendrites there are a host of differences. No problem in having a different opinion here though. We are from different disciplines.

Comment: @AliceD When did I say that I do not acknowledge the differences? (Also I don't think I come across as an unreceptive person.) They have both similarity and differences. In bipolar neurons they look quite similar as well. In pseudounipolar neurons axons carry both afferent and efferent signals. Biology has several cases of non-absolute rules. You can always find domains of similarity and differences.

Comment: i mean can axons act as afferent nerve fibers (receptors)?

Comment: I slightly modified the question based on your comment above to clarify this question to the best of my understanding - I added an answer too. Feel free to roll back my changes if it doesn't reflect your ideas. +1 for this question. Very enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**
The textbooks are right; the receptor part of sensory neurons is always considered to be the dendrite. Axons are nonetheless an integral part of some receptor types to send the signal to the brain. Other, more specialized sensory cells do not have an axon and therefore rely on secondary neurons to send the signal to the brain.

**Background**
There are three types of sensory cells, namely those with *free nerve endings*, those with *specialized dendritic structures*, and *specialized receptor cells that synapse directly onto a secondary neuron* (Fig. 1).

[image: sensory neurons]
<sup>Fig. 1. Types of sensory neurons. Source: [Premed HQ](https://www.premedhq.com/sensory-receptors).</sup>

1. Sensory neurons with free nerve endings have an exposed dendrite that functions as receptor. Examples are [nociceptors](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/Supplement_3/15596/F1.expansion.html) (pain receptors) and [hair follicle receptors](http://fog.ccsf.cc.ca.us/~mmalacho/anatomy/Skin/Sensors.html).
2. Other sensory neurons are complex cells that feature a dendritic region specialized for a particular receptor function. Examples are the [Pacinian corpuscle](http://humanphysiology.tuars.com/program/section1/1ch5/s1ch5_4.htm) and [olfactory neurons](http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v2/n2/fig_tab/nn0299_106_F1.html).
3. The most common receptor type are specialized receptor neurons that have no axon and need a secondary sensory neuron to send the signal to the brain. Examples are the [photoreceptor cells](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=photoreceptors&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI1r_Iq76FxwIVxiWmCh1MLQuQ&biw=1129&bih=566#imgrc=hp3Vn3YyU8V39M%3A) in the retina, the [hair cells](http://what-when-how.com/neuroscience/auditory-and-vestibular-systems-sensory-system-part-1/) in the cochlea and [Merkel cells](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24349/why-merkel-cells-are-innervated-by-axon-and-not-by-dendrite-end).

Answer (score 0):

> In all histology books, it is stated that all sensory nerve endings
>   (receptors) are made of dendrites which conduct sensation from
>   environment to body but it doesn't seem to be true.

The phrase "nerve endings" (or "free nerve endings". See [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_nerve_ending)) is typically associated with fine hairlike structures throughout the skin and organs that act as (one type of) touch, pain, or heat sensors. These are, yes, extensions of the dendrites of sensory neurons whose cell bodies live in the dorsal root ganglia of the spinal cord and who send the signal on via axons, either locally within the spinal cord or to brain structures.

But this is not the same as saying that all sensory structures of any sense modality are dendrites or extensions of them. Each sense has specialized cells to detect that sensory stimulus. The eye has photoreceptors (rods and cones), the ear has inner hair cells, the nose has olfactory receptor neurons, the tongue has taste cells, and the skin and organs have free nerve endings and specialized mechnoreceptors such as pacinian corpuscles. Most of these do the work of transducing the stimulus in a specialized receptor portion of the cell, such as the rod itself, or the cilia of a hair cell or ORN, etc., and then the signal is sent to the next cell in the sensory chain via a synapse, sometimes via a very short axon or just sort of axon "nub".